# Django file uploading error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i am trying to upload file but unable to do so,
my function in view,

```
def user_in(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
return render(request, 'accounts/logout.html')
else:
if request.method == 'POST':
form_new = Fileupload(request.POST, request.FILES )
if form_new.is_valid():
return redirect('in')
else:
form_new = Fileupload()
return render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new})
```

my form,

```
class Fileupload(forms.Form):
BrowseFile=forms.FileField()
class Meta:
model=User
```

and my template,

```
<form action="." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<h3>Welcome to DropBox<br><br></h3>
{% csrf_token %}
{{form_new.as_p}}
<p><input type="submit" value="Save" ></p>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{%else%}
<p>You must login first</p>
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Logout</a>
{% endif %}
<br>
</form>
```

after pressing submit button i do not see any doc in media location.
Am i doing something wrong or anything missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You have to use `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form` if you want to use `model=....` in `class Meta:`.

So I'll change like this...

```
class Fileupload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User # I guess BrowseFile field may be FileField()
```

If your model `User` is like this, you don't have to make BrowseFile field in your `Fileupload` form.

```
class User(...):
    BrowseFile = models.FileField()
```

So let's go further..

```
def user_in(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'accounts/logout.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_new = Fileupload(request.POST, request.FILES )
            if form_new.is_valid():
                return redirect('in')
        else:
            form_new = Fileupload()
        return render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new})
```

In your `views`, there is NOTHING you're saving what you've got in POST.

so let's change it ...

```
def user_in(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'accounts/logout.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_new = Fileupload(request.POST, request.FILES )
            if form_new.is_valid():
                form.save() # if you want it, you have to use forms.ModelForm 
                return redirect('in')
        else:
            form_new = Fileupload()
        return render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new})
```

Now you can see uploaded files in your somewhere upload folder.

> Note: you HAVE TO setup upload file location(`MEDIA_ROOT`) and `MEDIA_URL` in your `settings.py` !

Comment: regarding your sugeestion:

class Fileupload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User # I guess BrowseFile field may be FileField()
If your model User is like this, you don't have to make BrowseFile field in your Fileupload form.

class User(...):
    BrowseFile = models.FileField()

i used django 'user' inbuit model

Comment: If you're using inbuilt model, `BrowseFile` may not be exist. If you want to use that field, you can extend your `User` model by 2 solutions. First is making your own `User` model which inherits `AbstractBaseUser`, Second is making `UserInfo` model connected with `User` model One-To-One relationship.